# Access Suave self hosted app in Azure VM from internet

Tags: azure, f#, self-hosting, suave

I deployed a **Suave** selfhosted webapp that is accessible from `http://localhost:9001` inside an Azure VM *Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter* and am trying to make it accessible from outside the VM on `http://[my-vm-name].cloudapp.net:9001`.

It is a simple Hello world:

```
[<EntryPoint>] 
let main args = 
    startWebServer { defaultConfig with bindings = [ Types.HttpBinding.mk' Types.HTTP "127.0.0.1" 9001 ] } (OK "Hello world")
    0
```

[image: localhost accessible]

I already have:

1. Set up the inbounds and outbounds rules for port `9001` on the VM firewall
   [image]
   [image]
2. Added `9001` TCP and UDP endpoints on Azure portal

[image: azure portal endpoints]

All the solutions/tutorials I find don't specify more details than what I already did but I still can't access my webapp from outside the VM. What else am I missing?

Comment: this belongs on [sf]

Comment: @DanielA.White Author of Suave here, no it doesn't. The error was that he was binding to "127.0.0.1" instead of e.g. "0.0.0.0" or the public routable IP of the VM.

Comment: Thanks @Henrik for checking this. I managed to figure it out after Brad L. advised me to make sure I am binding to all addresses / interfaces and not just localhost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify what technology you are using to build your app but in many cases there are options to specify which addresses to bind to.  Make sure you are actually binding to all addresses / interfaces and not just to localhost.